# Using LinkedList instead of Vectors for customized Recurisive zip file comparision Tool

Tags: java, multithreading, vector, linked-list

I have written a custom tool that compares the structure and contents of two zipped files recursively. 
It check if the two file have same contents or not and identifies the missing files or files that have different size. 
This utility requires input files to be placed in two separate folders and each file explodes into two separate folders 
under their respective directories and size and individual file content related information are captured in different Vectors(java primitive sync list)by picking one file at a time.
I am using java Vectors to count the size and content of file and compare with each other as vector are synchronous and thread safe.
But, now, I want to change that to use Linked list. Can someone suggest a way to make this comparison thread safe. I can share the code if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a list thread safe you can wrap it like this.

```
List<SomeClass> threadSafeList = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<SomeClass>());
```

There are similar [wrappers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html) for other kinds of collections.